# java.lang.AbstractMethodError for deployed aar on WSO2 Application Server

Tags: java, apache-axis, wso2

After invoking an operation by "try it" using WSO2 Application Server, admin area. I get this error.
I have created a wsdl file using eclipse and generate server side code using Axis2 code generator, then I archive it using Axis2 archiver and deployed it in my Application server.
Can I attribute this problem to difference of Axis2 versions on WSo2 and my eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was attributed to jar files and their version! I used the axis2 1.4.0 for compiling  and code generation while the WSO2 application server used the axis2 1.6.0.1 version of the library. So this was making the error! Just changed the Axi2 1.4.0 to axis2 1.6.0.1 and everything went well.

Answer (score 0):

We had faced similar issue before on tomcat deployment. The issue was due to the conflict of jars in tomcat and our webapp. 
We had a few jars which were creating issues with loading of the tomcat jars(jasper-compiler, jasper-runtime etc).
Once we removed them, our application started working properly.

Comment: I have jasper-jdt_6.0.18.wso2v1, jasperreports_4.5.0.wso2v1, org.apache.jasper_5.5.17.v200806031609, org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.200.v20090520-1800
 and I don't know what would happen if I remove them.
Also what do you mean exactly with "etc"?

Comment: In our case, we were using maven to build the project. As a dependency of hadoop, there were a few jars like jasper-compiler-5.5.2.jar, jasper-runtime-5.5.2.jar,jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar,jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar. These jars were not allowing some of the tomcat required jars to be loaded. When we removed these 4 jars from our application, ours started to work. In your case, I do not know what are the conflicting jars.

Comment: Thanks, that would be helpful.